# Userpilot (history.pushState({}, "", e), history.pushState({}, "", window.location.href), history.back())

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I use external library in react app and there are some actions that opens another pages.

When I click to button with url e.g "/dashboard/reviews" it goes to "/dashboard/reviews" in chrome correctly but in safari go back to last page.

External library uses code like this

`onclick = (url) => { (history.pushState({}, "", url), history.pushState({}, "",    window.location.href), history.back()) }`

I left breakpoints and it is last raw of code before redirect

Question: Why this code below goes to page correctly in chrome but redirect to back in safari ?
And what this code actually do ?

`(history.pushState({}, "", url), history.pushState({}, "",    window.location.href), history.back()`

Comment: That code seems a bit weird, but if it's in an external library, all you can really do is report the issue to the author and/or use a different library. I'm not sure what we can really do to help given the information in the question.

Comment: _"And what this code actually do ?"_ - that's just three expressions, "joined" by the comma operator, isn't it? So it pushes `url` to the history first, then it pushes `window.location.href` - and then it goes back to the previous history entry. Which should be `url` again, I think. Not sure what the actual point of this is supposed to be - create some sort of "circular" history, so that when I go from current URL to `url`, and then when on there press the _forward_ button, I would land on the originating URL again ...?